# What is the chance of one player winning a chess tournament?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Person A plays a chess tournament against persons B and C. Person B is a professional, while person C is an amateur. Person A wins the tournament if they achieve at least $k$, $k<n$ consecutive victories in $n$ alternating games against persons B and C. As person B is a professional, the probability that person A will win in a single game against person B is less than the probability of A winning against person C in a single game. Against whom should person A play the first game to have a higher probability of winning the tournament, if $n$ is an odd number, and $k$ is an even number?

I found solution for $n=3$ and $k=2$, so person A should play first game against person B, but I don't know how to do generalised approach.

$$\begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
            P_B(A_3) - P_C(A_3) &= (P_B(BCB) + P_B(BC\bar{B}) + P_B(\bar{B}CB))\\ &-(P_C(CBC) + P_C(CB\bar{C}) + P_C(\bar{C}BC)) \\
            &=(2-p_B)p_Bp_C - (2-p_C)p_Bp_C \\
            &=(p_C-p_B)p_Bp_C\\
            &>0.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}$$

Comment: Your $n=3,k=2$ answer is optimal for the case for when A has to win at least $2$ consecutive games when playing $3$, but not when A has to win any $2$ or more out of the $3$ games

Comment: Parity of $k$ as nothing to do in the problem, it is only a bait to disturb you. You will play $\frac{n-1}{2}$ games against B and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ against C, plus 1 game against one opponent you can choose. Which opponent do you choose for this additive game ?

Comment: Except if one word is missing in the question, and A has to win k consecutive games !

Comment: @Lourrran yes, sorry, edited...

Comment: You can tolerate a maximum of $\frac{n-k + 1}2$ losses against the first player you play, while you can only tolerate a maximum of $\frac{n-k - 1}2$ losses against the other player. Best to have the larger toleration for the player against which you are more likely to accrue losses.